# The expression you have entered refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exist error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to open 2 ADODB recordsets on a button click event like:

```
    Private Sub btn1_Click()
        Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
        Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset

         rs.Open "UPDATE table ITEM = " & Me.ITEM & " where ID = " & ID, CurrentProject.Connection
       rs.Close
       Set rs = Nothing

      rst.Open "Update Table2 set Item2 = " & Me.Item2,CurrentProject.Connection

End Sub
```

The first error I get is on `rs.close` where it says:

> Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.

I am really confused about this error as I have clearly not closed the record set `rs`.

But even when I remove `rs.close` I get:

> The expression you have entered refers to an object that is closed or
>   doesn't exist

on the

`rst.Open "Update Table2 set Item2 = " & Me.Item2,CurrentProject.Connection`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error (on `rs.Close`) happened because the recordset was never opened.

Your `UPDATE` (when you included the `SET` keyword) executed successfully, but an `UPDATE` does not return records.  So the recordset was not opened.  Run the following code to clarify the situation ...

```vba
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strUpdate As String

strUpdate = "UPDATE table SET ITEM = " & Me.item & " where ID = " & id
rs.Open strUpdate, CurrentProject.Connection
If rs.State = adStateClosed Then
    Debug.Print "can't close recordset because it's already closed"
Else
    rs.Close
End If
```

When you want to execute an `UPDATE`, you don't need a recordset; you don't even need ADO.  You can just do this ...

```vba
CurrentDb.Execute strUpdate, dbFailOnError
```

Regarding your second error, I'm unsure about the cause, but suspect the problem is in building the statement text.  Suggest you add this to your code and run it ...

```vba
Debug.Print "Update Table2 set Item2 = " & Me.Item2
```

If that doesn't trigger the same error, copy the statement text from the Immediate window and paste it for testing into SQL View of a new query in the Access query designer.  If you're not familiar with the Immediate window, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> will take you there.

Comment: You are right about both errors. The second error was in fact occurring because I closed the form before executing that line. This made `me.Item2` invalid. Sorry I forgot to add the form close code above.

Answer (score 1):

The `.Open` method is not for an *action* query but for a *select* query.

Comment: I am sure this is not true because my first  `rs.open` code does update the table

Answer (score 1):

Since you are evaluating `update` statements, you should use the [`.Execute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/miscellaneous/execute-method-ado-connection) method of the [ADODB Connection object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/connection-object-ado) rather than the `.Open` method.